# Concatenate variable in PrintArea

Tags: excel, vba

This should be really simple.  But having difficulty.  I created a variable call `numCountRows`, which will count number of rows in a range and then adds 13.  I tried the following line of code, but this results in run-time error 1004. The text you entered is not a valid reference or defined name.

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "ActiveSheet.Range(""" & "A14:O" & numCountRows & ")"
```

If `numCountRows = 1`, the line of code would read like this:

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveSheet.Range("A14:O14")
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only include the range of cells; do not include the sheet name. For example:

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A14:O" & numCountRows
```